# Visual Studio crash on start (System.Globalization.TextInfo)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Right after the splash screen it shows a popup with

> The type initializer for 'System.Globalization.TextInfo' threw an exception.

and that's it.

Does anyone have any ideas? Removing VS 2010 and reinstalling with SP1 produced the same error several times during installation and then again on startup.

Comment: I googled a bit, are the framework installed correctly? Are you under Wine?

Comment: I could not resolve it with the help of google. I am under Win7 64 Bit and the same installation has been working before. Did never modify it since first install (except installing SP1 but it worked after that as well).

Comment: Thanks for bringing the .net framework back to my attention :) Completely removing and reinstalling .net 4.0 helped. the repair function it offers did not do the trick earlier for whatever reason. No idea at all what could corrupt it - the machine isn't used for anything else.

Comment: Are you opening a specific project or are you just starting VS when it crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the correct installation of the .NET framework 4.0 (and possibly older) and try to reinstall them.

If you are under wine; the problem can be different in many ways.

Comment: thanks Edward, as i commented above that's how i already solved it after your hint :) i would still be interested in how that could have happened in the first place and maybe how to prevent it. I usually would think it was a incorrect uninstall or update of a compnent but i never did anything like that.